# Sql-server how to store database with this relation

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relationship

I have no idea about how to create database like this
Example i have a lot of item category
And i have person table and they're own some item.

**Fruit table :**

id item

1  Apple

2  Grape

3  Cherry

**Snack table :**

id item

1  Chip

2  Hot dog

**Person table**

id name

1  Jame

2  Jack

And i want to create something like

Jame has Apple , Chip
Jack has Apple , Hot dog

So please suggest me some way to create this Database

Thank you very much for any answer

Answer (score 0):

This is many-to-many relationships (one person can have multiple items, every item can be owned by multiple persons). But first, I don't think there's need to have two Snack and Fruit tables. You better merge them and add 'type'. Like this:

```
create table Food (
  id int,
  item varchar(255),
  typeid int
);
create table FoodType (
  id int,
  type varchar(255)
);
```

Then, you'll have to add intermediate table for storing person and food id's:

```
create table FoodPerson (
  PersonId int,
  FoodId int
);
```

Sample select from this structure would be:

```
select
   p.Name, f.Item, t.Type
from Person p
join FoodPerson fp
  on p.id=fp.personid
join Food f
  on f.id=fp.foodid
join FoodType t
  on t.id=f.typeid
```

Answer (score 0):

i think Frik is right.

else you have to Create two more table like PersonFruit and Personsnack.
But in case your type(like Vegetable) increases then one more such table .

So i think i go with frikozoid answer .